# Using TinyMCE Advanced with plugin's textarea - Wordpress

Tags: tinymce, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a custom plugin in Wordpress. I also have the TinyMCE Advanced Wordpress plugin activated and working.

I created a normal HTML textarea, and converted it into a TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor, using the `class="theEditor"` attribute. The problem is, it's Wordpress' own TinyMCE implementation, and NOT the TinyMCE Advanced plugin's implementation, which means I miss out on all its features, including the (most important for my purposes) "stop removing `<p>` and `<br>` tags" option.

How do I make the textarea trigger TinyMCE Advanced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at these two articles:

- <del>http://allcreatives.net/2011/02/02/using-the-native-wordpress-tinymce-wysiwyg-editor-with-your-custom-post-meta-textareas/</del>
- <del>http://www.keighl.com/2010/01/tinymce-in-wordpress-plugins/</del>

And check the **the_editor** (*/wp-includes/general-template.php -> line 1771*) and the **wp_tiny_mce** (*/wp-admin/includes/post.php -> line 1377*) functions too.

### Updated the links

These links are dead, but can be reached in the internet archive here:

[allcreative.net page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120224131828/http://allcreatives.net/2011/02/02/using-the-native-wordpress-tinymce-wysiwyg-editor-with-your-custom-post-meta-textareas)

[keighl.com page](https://web.archive.org/web/20111009014120/http://keighl.com/2010/01/tinymce-in-wordpress-plugins/)

Comment: I remember trying the steps in the second link and it didn't work well, I don't remember why.

The first link looks good, I'll try it out later, Thanks!

Comment: The links to these articles are dead.